# RewriteRule to redirect whole domain to get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a **whole url** to a **query parameter** with a RewriteRule in .htaccess

for example:  `http://server.com/http://google.com` should be redirected to

```
http://server.com/index.php?url=http://google.com
```

so far i'm just able to make this work: `http://server.com/google.com` but when a `:` or `/` is contained, it doesn't work..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

thanks for help!

Comment: `http://server.com/http://google.com` is not a valid URL, so won't ever get to the host to be rewritten.

Comment: Although you're not asking about it specifically, I believe using URL encoding (which you don't appear to be doing, in the above example) is at least a piece of the puzzle you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` patter strips multiple `/` into one, better use `RewriteCond` here:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.php?url=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. But then it's not possible to work with relative paths anymore! So only absolute paths with this solution

Comment: Any path segment can be captured this way but just remember `%{REQUEST_URI}` always represents full path.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the `TLD` and then add the `http://` in the rule. This is how I would do it.

This is the way I would use it so it doesn't "look" invalid. `http://server.com/google.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?url=http://$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```